# Почему разные проекты не работают с ldaps java?

Tags: java, сертификат, зависимости

Есть код для создания пользователя в ldaps (636 порт).
Все сертификаты установил. Код работает, но когда я его вставляю в другой проект, у меня выдает ошибку "SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" говоря о том, что сертификата сервера нет.
Что примечательно оба скажем проекта я запускаю на своем ПК, где 100% установлен сертификат. Один проект отрабатывает и создает пользователя, другой проект выдает исключение.

Что я уже сделал:

- Удалил сертификат и заново установил
- Попросил перевыпустить сертификат у системника
- Обновил все зависимости в  pom
- На том проекте где не работает ldaps, протестировал через порт ldap - работает

Полный код исключения :
create error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: server10.******:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: server10.******:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку сам. Надо смотреть какой путь при компиляции выдает "JAVA_HOME", и в том пути надо добавлять сертификаты.
Один проект смотрел у меня "JAVA_HOME" по одному пути, а вот другой смотрел на другой путь. Получается тот который смотрел в другую папку там не было сертификатов папке jre\lib\security